# Getting error when trying to run watir-webdriver/cucumber on windows

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am getting the following error when trying to run my cucumber/watir-webdriver/ruby tests.

Failed to navigate to http://test.domain.com. This usually means that a call to COM method [WebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed. (Selenium::Webdriver::Error::UnknownError)

It works fine if I run it in firefox. Just getting this issue in IE.

Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: You've downloaded InternetExplorerDriver and added it to PATH?  And "set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value" in IE (under Tools > Internet Options > Security)?

Comment: I have. When I run the test it opens the browser but closes almost immediately with that message I posted.

Comment: Does it work if you follow this instructions? https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/installation/windows.md

Comment: The issue is that I need to authenticate to get to the site. It works in Firefox but it does not like it in IE. I am using https://user:password@test.domain.com. Any ideas how I can get around this?